# Creating a new column in PySpark, and indexing a row in the dataframe that returns a value 1 before

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, filtering, data-cleaning, alteryx

I have a pyspark dataframe that I am cleaning and it is based off of logic previously built into Alteryx.

Inside the dataframe, you picture there being the following columns: `col1 = 'Part', col2 = 'Tool'`

I am creating a new column called 'Fill' and this column is created with this alteryx logic assigned to it:

'''`if !IsNull(Part) then Part ELSE [row-1:Fill]`'''

How would in Pyspark would I go about taking the previous row and putting its 'Fill' value in the new row if the condition is met?

Comment: `[row-1:Fill]` What does this do?

Comment: Also , can you add your input and output datasets with proper details? It will be much better to understand your requirement here.